# I have a recovery partition but OS X doesn't use it for recovery

Tags: macos, recovery

I need to start my El Capitan OS X in Recovery Mode to run `csrutil disable`.
When I restart holding <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> the Mac directly boots to Internet Recovery Mode. But I need a local recovery partition because the online version doesn't provide csrutil!

I check if I lost my local recovery partition but it seems present.

```
➜  ~ diskutil list                                                   
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            250.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

Any suggestion what I can do to re-enable my recovery partition?

Comment: You restart your Mac and hold down the alt/option key. The recovery partition should appear as an labeled icon for you to select.

Comment: David Anderson beat me to it. Just hold down the option key and power on the mac, continuing holding option key until the startup options appear.

Comment: Thanks to both of you.. Unfortunately the screen show only my main partition and the select menu for WiFi

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use http://musings.silvertooth.us/2014/07/recovery-partition-creator-3-8/ to rewrite my recovery partition from el captian installation download from app store.

Thanks @David Anderson for good indication

Answer (score 1):

If can not boot to your recovery partition, there are two alternate ways to enable/disable SIP.

1. Create a USB flash drive installer. You can plug the flash drive
   into the USB port and restart with the alt/option key held down. To
   create the flash drive, you will need to download El Capitan from
   the App Store. You do **not** reinstall El Capitan. Instead you use
   the instruction given [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) to create the flash drive.
2. The other alternative would be to install [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/). During
   booting you can select to enable/disable SIP. You would not have to
   actually install rEFInd to your internal disk. You can install rEFInd
   to a flash drive as well. See [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/sip.html#disable_in_refind) for more information.

The advantage to the first method is the flash drive completely replaces your Recovery Partition. In other words, everything you can do once booted from the internal recovery partition will be available when booted from the flash drive. Of course, this requires downloading all of El Capitan which is several Gigabytes in size. If you have a slow internet connection speed, then the second method, involving installing rEFInd to a flash drive, would be a more favorable option.